# rails url_helper placing params where format should be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, rails-routing, url-helper

I'm trying to get Rails generated _path methods to give me

`/terms_and_conditions?utm_source=source&utm_campaign=pain#some_link`

So I've tried the following in a controller:

```
utm_params = {"utm_source" => "sauce", "utm_campaign" => "pain"} # from params
redirect_to terms_and_conditions_path(utm_params.merge(anchor: 'some_link')
```

and I get this, with the anchor as a param:

`/terms_and_conditions?anchor=some_link&utm_source=source&utm_campaign=pain`

If I try

`terms_and_conditions_path(utm_params, anchor: 'some_link')`

I get the hash in place of format, instead of proper params (i.e. no `?`):

`/terms_and_conditions.utm_source=source&utm_campaign=pain#some_link`

How am I supposed to pass params on AND add an anchor?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is bonkers.

Looks like the problem is Hash vs HashWithIndifferentAccess; when you do `params.to_h`, you get a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` - which the url helpers don't treat like a `Hash`, and can't pull the anchor out of - so the anchor becomes part of the params.

`params.to_hash` gives you a "real" hash; merging `anchor: 'blah'` works as expected.

(note: originally, I thought it was because the keys were strings - but it was a red herring; `HashWithIndifferentAccess#symbolize_keys` returns a real hash)

At this point, I'd love to reference the autogenerated `x_path` api docs, but I'm pretty sure that just doesn't exist, and the code is to confusing to follow. Trial and error won the day here.